# How to validate bean on Spring's WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-webclient

I guess the answer is no, as all references to Bean Validation in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) are related to the server side.

Is there any support for Bean Validation on the client's side? So that I can validate my entities before even sending them to the server.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

You can use [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/project-summary.html) which is part of JSR-303 [implementations](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)

> Apache Commons Validator provides the building blocks for both **client side validation** and server side data validation. It **may be used standalone or with a framework like Struts**.

Or use relevant [proprietary client-side solution](http://tapestry.apache.org/bean-validation.html)

> JSR-303 doesn’t cover client-side validation, so web frameworks supporting this JSR need to come up with proprietary client-side solutions. Tapestry provides client-side validation for the following JSR-303 constraints

Comment: Strange, as JPA "client"/ EntityManager is supported.
And neither Jackson nor Spring WebClient provide any out-of-the-box integration?

Comment: The question (title) was about Spring WebClient. It shouldn't depend on the device type, should it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call validator manually:

```
@Autowired
private final SmartValidator validator;

BeanPropertyBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(entity, "entity");
validator.validate(entity, errors);
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
    //...
}
```